# Why does unxz return this invalid argument error?

Tags: linux, kali-linux, extract, img, sparsefile

I'm using the command unxz on Linux (Ubuntu) to convert an .img.xz file to just an .img file.

The command I'm entering is as follows:

```
unxz kali-2017.01-rpi2.img.xz
```

But it just returns this error:

```
unxz: kali-2017.01-rpi2.img: Seeking failed when trying to create a sparse file: Invalid argument
```

Anybody know why?

Comment: Have you tried using the --no-sparse argument?

Comment: Also, do you have enough space on your partition?

Comment: @music2myear I don't know how much space the file needs, but I'll try --no-sparse. Would it have a large effect on the outcome?

Comment: Based entirely on reading just the manpage for unxz, I learned that the --no-sparse argument will likely slow the process down, but it will also use less space for the decompression, as the sparefile appears to be in addition to both the original packed file and the output uncompressed file(s).

Comment: Regarding space needs, it'll be at least the same size as the original image, and likely a bit bigger. How much bigger depends on factors that you have access to but I don't.

Comment: Finally, what troubleshooting have you performed yourself? What research? Are you only trying to decompress the file? Have you checked proper syntax for unxz?

Comment: @music2myear I'm going to try --no-sparse now, will report back

Comment: @music2myear It worked! Kali flashed to the SD card perfectly and is now running on my rpi 3. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It may be an issue of insufficient disk space, or of permissions on the file structure.

By default, a sparsefile is created during extraction as a sort of scratch or working directory. The sparsefile allows for quicker extraction usually, with the tradeoff being that the entire process needs more disk space. This is then deleted when the process is complete.

Using the `--no-sparsefile` option tells `xz --decompress` (or `unxz`, which is the same thing) to decompress the archive without using a sparsefile.